# Autoloader tries to include Wordpress files like WPSEO/Frontend.php and fails

Tags: magento-1.9, log, wordpress, varien-autoload, system.log

My `system.log` file reads the below set of 9 items on repeat and just constantly fills up to a gig or more but I can't understand why it thinks these things are installed when they aren't. How do I deal with Varien/Autoload.php so it will stop all this?

```
2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(ReallySimpleCaptcha.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'ReallySimpleCaptcha.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/local:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/community:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/core:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(WPSEO/Frontend.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'WPSEO/Frontend.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/local:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/community:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/core:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(All/In/One/SEO/Pack.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'All/In/One/SEO/Pack.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/local:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/community:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/core:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/local:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/community:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/app/code/core:/home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-25T14:35:45+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Static function Minify_Inline::minify() should not be abstract  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/Minify/Minify/Inline.php on line 8
```

Comment: It appears to be looking for files which are linked with a WordPress installation, are you using a WordPress integration like the one by Fishpig?

Comment: Nope. There's a magento install and a wordpress install completely separate of each other and no plugins connecting the two. Which is why I don't understand!

Comment: Is the WordPress installation in the same directory or in a subdirectory of WordPress (or vice-versa)?

Comment: wordpress is public_html
store is publich_html/store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to move your Magento install from that subdirectory into a subdomain. So you would then have store.yourdomain.com.

A WordPress plugin appears to be triggering the Mage Autoload function. Alternatively you could disable your WordPress plugins until the errors stop and then you will find the culprit.

It seems likely a caching/minifying plugin may do this if that helps.

Comment: Yeah we have a subdomain setup and all that. Just a lot of structure to move.

Comment: Granted it's not an ideal solution but by simply using commands at SSH level you could move the entire Magento install in seconds and redirect the subdomain to use its own structure entirely.

Answer (score 2):

What Varien_Autoload tries is to find files for the following classes:

```
ReallySimpleCaptcha
WPSEO_Frontend
All_In_One_SEO_Pack
Woocommerce
```

Search your code base for these to find out where they are referenced. To me it looks like these are classes from Wordpress plugins. The last error also proves that you included Wordpress code - maybe from the Fishpig Wordpress integration.

A likely reason for these messages is that some wordpress plugin uses `if (class_exists('one of those class names'))` to find out if other plugins are installed. But `class_exists` triggers the autoloader and while the Wordpress autoloader doesn't care if it doesn't find the class, the Magento autoloader just includes the file name where it thinks the class should be without checking if it really exists (which is stupid and I consider it a bug in Magento).

That's why you never should use `class_exists` in Magento.

If you can't fix the problem within Wordpress, you could patch `Varien_Autoload`:

- copy the file to `app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php`
- add the following lines

  ```
  if (stream_resolve_include_path($classFile) === false) {
      return false;
  }
  ```

  before

  ```
  return include $classFile;
  ```

Comment: Yeah I'm just going to patch it. I don't understand why it's going through and just pulling stuff out of my wordpress install when there's no reason. Even after the patch it's still doing things like 

2015-06-25T15:10:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: today_view  in /home/fantomwo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mechanic-visitor-counter/wp-statsmechanic.php on line 120

Comment: Since you installed Magento in a subdirectory below Wordpress, I assume that requests get routed through the `index.php` of Wordpress and then back to Magento because both .htaccess files apply. The cleanest solution would be to install Wordpress and Magento in separate directories. Alternatively you could change the Wordpress .htaccess to not apply any rewrite rules for the store subdirectory

Comment: The patch solution here would also mean that Magento error logging was no longer able to properly log include() errors though surely? So you may as well just disable error logging all together which doesn't seem a viable option.

Comment: I actually just started disabling wordpress plugins and was able to stop it for now.

Comment: @performadigital No, that's not the case. Usually you get two errors "include failed" and "class not found". The "class not found" error remains. In cases like here, where there is only a "include failed" error, it comes from a `class_exists` check and should not have triggered an error in the first place

Comment: @new2programming brace yourself, you will get other errors as long as you don't separate Magento and Wordpress properly (see comment above)

Comment: Yeah. I'll have to make the move eventually. Right now I'm just desperately trying to fix the problem in my other post (issue with add to cart button not adding and just returning to homepage on configurable items) so as to get the store back up and running. Then I can make a migration another day.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is to add some dummy files in the `app/code/community` folder eg
'ReallySimpleCaptcha.php'
That worked for me, just make sure that the start with `<?php`